# Configure navbar to show different buttons, when different type of users login Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, header

I Just wanted to ask this:
I am doing a header in which I check if the user that is logged in, has an Admin or a User role.
If he is an administrator, it must show Administration (the name of the button). If he is a user, it must show the name of the user's name along (the name of the button) with 2 dropdown links, profile and logout.

So far I have done this:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    @if ((Auth::check() && (Auth::user()->roles()->id=1)) //Administration area
        <a href="{{ route('admin.dashboard') }}" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" ><i class="fa fa-user fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i> Administration</a>
    @elseif(Auth::check() && (Auth::user()->roles()->id=3)) //Simple user area
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" ><i class="fa fa-user fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ Auth::user()->username }} <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="{{ route('user.profile') }}">User Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ route('user.logout') }}">Log out</a></li>
    </ul>
    @else
        @include('user.login') //login area
    @endif
</li>
```

When no users are logged in, the login button is being shown.

When a users is logged in, eg a User, it shows me Administrator button, the 1st If. But that's wrong.

It doesn't seem to get out of the If and can't see why.

I must say that I access `roles` table via a pivot table `user_role` that's why I use `user()->roles()->id`. When I had roles inside `users` table, it was working.
Does anyone has any idea? Anything would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If relation between `User` and `Role` is one-to-one, this will work:

```
@if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->roles->id == 1)
```

So, you should use `==` instead of `=`.

`==` compare the value if its equals.
`=` assign a value to a variable.

**UPDATE**
You said you're using many-to-many here. In this case you should use eager loading to load `roles()` relation and pass this data to the view:

```
$userWithRoles = auth()->user()->load('roles');
```

Then you should use [`contains()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-contains) method to check if user has role you're looking for:

```
@if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->roles->contains(1))
```

Comment: I am sorry for not mentioning but the table's relation is many-to-many.

Comment: Please check updated answer. Also, why are you using many-to-many? User can really have many roles, like Admin can be `1` and `3` at the same time?

Comment: id=1 is for Admin and id=3 is for user. Of course there is and a 3rd type of user (id 2) but that's not important. So you think its better to configure the relation for one-to-one?

Comment: I think it's better to keep role id in `users` table if you will not modify roles in future. It's much faster solution since all app requests will load just one table instead of two (or three with many-to-many). And it's better solution for big apps with a lot of data related logic, but with simple roles system.

Comment: I will keep that in mind. But for now, I get Call to a member function load() on null with $userWithRoles. Where should I have this piece of code? Not in my view right?

Comment: `null` means that user is not logged in. So just do simple check like `if (auth()->check())` and only then load the relation.

Comment: Well it seems that @if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->roles->contains(1))
does the work I want but I'm not using $userWithRoles = auth()->user()->load('roles'); Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can use it without `load()` but in this case Laravel will create additional queries (read about eager loading in docs to understand how it work). Glad it helped. )

Answer (score 0):

You make a mistake to use assign operator `=` instead comparison `==`.
Try below code:

```
@if (Auth::guest())
    @include('user.login') //login area
@else
    @if(access()->user()->roles[0]->id == 1)
        //Administration area
    @elseif(access()->user()->roles[0]->id == 3)
        //Simple user area
    @endif
@endif
```

NOTE: What about the other then users which having role id 2 OR 4..? Please update your code with it.